# Выбор элементов с помощью jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Как выбрать с помощью jquery **именно** 4 последних элемента LI, которые являются, что очевидно, дочерними к UL?

```html
<section class="menu">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>Пункт 1</li>
    <li>Пункт 2</li>
    <li>Пункт 3</li>
    <li>Пункт 4</li>
    <li>Пункт 5</li>
    <li>Пункт 6</li>
    <li>Пункт 7</li>
    <li>Пункт 8</li>
    <li>Пункт 9</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно сделать таким вот образом. Для наглядности и поменял цвет последних 4 элементов. 
:nth-child(n+6) означает «Начать с шестого элемента в списке и выделить каждый следующий элемент».

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li:nth-child(n+6)').css('color', 'red');    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="menu">
  <ul class="list">
    <li>Пункт 1</li>
    <li>Пункт 2</li>
    <li>Пункт 3</li>
    <li>Пункт 4</li>
    <li>Пункт 5</li>
    <li>Пункт 6</li>
    <li>Пункт 7</li>
    <li>Пункт 8</li>
    <li>Пункт 9</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Если количество элементов может меняться тогда пишем такой код

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var num = $('li').length - 3;
  var elem = 'li:nth-child(n ' + num + ')';
  $(elem).css('color', 'red');    
});
```

Comment: Если будет 20(+-) пунктов и нужно выбрать именно 4 последних?